# getVersionNumber() me retorna undefined no Ionic

Tags: ionic, angular, apache-cordova

Preciso verificar a versão do aplicativo para fazer validações, o problema é que a promisse getVersionNumber() está me retornando undefined.

Tentei algo como:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    let versaoApp;
    this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then(version => {
      versaoApp = version;
    });

    this.dialogs.alert(versaoApp);
```

Porém dentro do alert é retornado undefined.

No meu config.xml, está preenchido a versão da seguinte maneira:

```
<widget id="idapp" version="0.0.4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando mostrar um valor que ainda não retornou no *promisse*, precisa colocar o `alert` no lugar certo:

```
 this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then(version => {
      versaoApp = version;
      this.dialogs.alert(versaoApp);
    });
```

Além disso, é importante checar se o plugin está instalado e referenciado corretamente, veja mais aqui: [ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version/)

Answer (score 1):

Inclua o alert dentro da função. Da forma como está, ele pode estar respondendo antes de verificar a versão.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  let versaoApp;
  this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then(version => {
    versaoApp = version;
    this.dialogs.alert(versaoApp);
  });
```

Certifique-se também de que você está testando em IOS ou Android.